# There is 403 error when I upload data through datastore using AzureML

Tags: azure, http-status-code-403, datastore, azure-machine-learning-service

I just want to upload data on my local laptop to datastore.
But there is an HTTP 403 error.

Could you please tell me how do I upload data?

There are error messages.

> > > ds
> > >
> > > ds.upload(src_dir = './MNIST_data/', target_path='MNIST_data', overwrite=True, show_progress=True)
> > >       Client-Request-ID=5b78750a-ee2f-11e8-bf9a-b46bfcb19fb2 Retry policy did not allow for a retry: Server-Timestamp=Thu, 22 Nov 2018 08:19:40 GMT, HTTP status code=40./BODY>ror 403. The request URL is forbidden.
> > >
> > > set=us-ascii">//www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml\data\azure_storage_datastore.py", line 380, in upload
> > >           self._file_share_upload
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml\data\azure_storage_datastore.py", line 235, in _start_upload_task
> > >           task_fn = task_generator(target_file_path, src_file_path)
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml\data\azure_storage_datastore.py", line 451, in _file_share_upload
> > >           if not self.file_service.exists(self.container_name, dirpath):
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml_vendor\azure_storage\file\fileservice.py", line 1306, in exists
> > >           _dont_fail_not_exist(ex)
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml_vendor\azure_storage\common_error.py", line 97, in _dont_fail_not_exist
> > >           raise error
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml_vendor\azure_storage\file\fileservice.py", line 1303, in exists
> > >           self._perform_request(request, expected_errors=expected_errors)
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml_vendor\azure_storage\common\storageclient.py", line 381, in _perform_request
> > >           raise ex
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml_vendor\azure_storage\common\storageclient.py", line 306, in _perform_request
> > >           raise ex
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml_vendor\azure_storage\common\storageclient.py", line 292, in _perform_request
> > >           HTTPError(response.status, response.message, response.headers, response.body))
> > >         File "C:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\azureml_vendor\azure_storage\common_error.py", line 115, in _http_error_handler
> > >           raise ex
> > >       azure.common.AzureHttpError: Forbidden
> > >       
> > >       Forbidden
> > >
> > > ### Forbidden URL
> > >
> > > ---
> > >
> > > HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden.

Comment: did you authenticate yourself?

Comment: YES. I configured default datastore.

Comment: I solved this problem... 
>>> ds.upload(src_dir = './MNIST_data', target_path='MNIST_data', overwrite=True, show_progress=True)
$AZUREML_DATAREFERENCE_82635d4c9eb148babf000023a453733b

I just removed '/' in src_dir... and then It works!

Comment: Can u upload the script?

Answer (score 0):

The upload function does not accepted trailing / in src_dir

Change:

```
s.upload(src_dir = './MNIST_data/', target_path='data')
```

Into:

```
s.upload(src_dir = './MNIST_data', target_path='data')
```

MINJI PARK supplied the correct answer himself in the comments